# Best practice to load pre-request resources before loading pages

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have an application store with following pages

/stores/:store_id/
/stores/:store_id/products/
/stores/:store_id/products/:produc_id

User can directly access **/stores/:store_id/products/:produc_id**
Hoever, before loading stores and products.

I need to do a bunch of requests.

- /validateUser
- /loadUserInfo

However, if the user has already verified, I don't want to call, /validateUser, /loadUserInfo again and again.

Because I have about 50 pages in my application.
I don't want to put above checks 50 times in each page or included in the above pages.

Anyway to run the check first before loading any page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is, are you using any routing lib? Even if you aren't you could create high order functions (HOC) to achive your goal.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const withAuthentication = (Component) => (props) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuthentication = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setAuth(true);
        setLoading(false);
      }, 2000);
    };
    checkAuthentication();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {auth ? <Component {...props} /> : <div>No permission component</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

const Div = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return <div>Test</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  const Comp = withAuthentication(Div);

  return (
    <div>
      <Comp match={{ params: ["foo"] }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

It's just a fast draft, it could be with a lot of bugs. After this you could wrap all your components into this HOC and they will be kind of safe

Comment: cool~ i'm using **react-router-dom** however, when i used your approcah...  the protected compo won't have access on **props.match.params** any more...

Comment: You can pass the props through the components, I will edit the answer