# How to get updated constructor data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios, react-hooks

i am creating a private route and this is the Auth js file.

**Auth.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

class Auth{
    constructor(){
        this.Authenticated = false;
    }

    CheckAuth(cb){
        axios.get('/api/get_me')
          .then(res => {
              if (res.data.logged_in == true) {
                this.Authenticated = true;
              }
          })
          .catch(err =>{
            this.Authenticated = false;
          });
        cb();
    }

    isAuthenticated(){
        return this.Authenticated;
    }
}

export default new Auth();
```

i am calling it from my private route component but always getting false Like it always get the first **this.Authenticated** value and not updating so **how can i do it and what is my problem**?

**Private.jsx**

```
import React, { Component, useEffect  } from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import auth from './Auth';

export const  ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
  return(
    <Route 
      {...rest}
        render={props =>{
          console.log(auth.isAuthenticated());
          if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            return <Component></Component>
          }
          else{
            return(
            <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location}}}></Redirect>)
          }
          
        }}
    />
  )
}
```

and this the api call data.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: In React - unless you use something that adds actual reactivity like MobX - you have to use the built-in state mechanisms and none of your JS objects are plain JS objects anymore. That is: you have to use `useState` for variables instead of regular variables and you can only mutate them with the state setter.

Comment: In addition to that, where are you calling CheckAuth to change the value? It sure looks like you never do, so the value will never change.

Comment: samuei basically i am new in react so i am not good at react can you please tell how to call it?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for this is creating a HOC (high order component).

I've just wrote a example of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67134553/best-practice-to-load-pre-request-resources-before-loading-pages/67134736#67134736)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const withAuthentication = (Component) => (props) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuthentication = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setAuth(true);
        setLoading(false);
      }, 2000);
    };
    checkAuthentication();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {auth ? <Component {...props} /> : <div>No permission component</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

const Div = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return <div>Test</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  const Comp = withAuthentication(Div);

  return (
    <div>
      <Comp match={{ params: ["foo"] }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help]. If the same answer answers this question and the other one, you don't repost the answer, you vote to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to not use an object to do think like this in **react**.

React use Hooks and Hooks is your solution.

Here is your class refactored using Hooks :

```js
function useAuth{
    const [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(null);
    const isAuthenticated = auth !== null
   
    React.useEffect(() => {
       axios.get('/api/get_me')
          .then(res => {
                setAuth(res.data)
          })
          .catch(err =>{
                setAuth(null)
          });
    }

    return { auth, isAuthenticated ) 

}

export default new useAuth();
```

And you can provide this `isAuthenticated` using [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or using props like this :

```js
function App() {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
  return (
     <Switch>
        <ProtectedRoute isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}>
          <Component />
        </ProtectedRoute>
     </Switch>
  )
}

export const  ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component, isAuthenti ...rest}) => {
  return(
    <Route 
      {...rest}
        render={props =>{
          console.log(auth.isAuthenticated());
          if (isAuthenticated) {
            return <Component></Component>
          }
          else{
            return(
            <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location}}}></Redirect>)
          }
          
        }}
    />
  )
}
```